# $m^*(A\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$) = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m (A\cap E_k$) ,$E_k$ is a countable disjoint collection of measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis

Let {$E_k$}$_{k=1}^\infty$ be a countable disjoint collection of measurable sets.

Prove that for any set A, $m^*(A\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$) = $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(A\cap E_k$)

I'm wondering if I can prove it by induction.

By induction, it seems like I prove "finitely many things."

Or is it okay if I use induction?

Comment: there is something that I don't understand:  the LHS and the RHS are not the same setwise like $A\cup _1^\infty E_k$ is not the same set as $\cup_1^\infty A\cap E_k$

Comment: @Spotty I edited. Sorry I forgot this